# I lose the image when start installation of ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, screen

did not have this problem in version 11.04, I had in version 9.10. 
when it starts to load the image of ubuntu 11.10  the screen make a flash and then shows a number of very fine continuous stripes that occupy the entire screen. The system still works but I can not see anything. 
I think it has to do with the resolution when it change when it starts booting. 
Somebody can help. I have a Dell Inspiron 1501. processor SEMPRON 1.7 and 2GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Did you MD5 test the .iso image before you burned it to CD/DVD or wrote it to the USB flash drive? If not, please [do that now](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). If that doesn't check out, you'll have to redownload the .iso image, MD5 test the new image, and (assuming the new one checks out) burn a new disc or write it to the USB flash drive again.

Did you verify that the live CD/DVD/USB was written correctly and is readable by the machine on which you're installing? To do that, boot from it, and immediately when you see the person and keyboard icons at the bottom center of the screen, press Spacebar, select your language, and select "Check disc for defects". (This goes for USB flash drives as well as CD's and DVD's.) If that doesn't check out, you'll have to burn a new disc or re-write the .iso image to the USB flash drive (and run this test on it again).

If the installation medium checks out as described above and you still have this problem, it can most often be solved by [using the `nomodeset` boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132). After installing, you'll probably need to specify `nomodeset` when booting the system, and then make the setting permanent (all of which is detailed in that forum thread). However, it is possible that after installing you may be able to enable different video drivers in **Additional Drivers** to fix the problem, as well.

If the above advice does not help, please edit your question to include the make and model of your video card.